# How can Parameters and Sets in an abstract pyomo model be operated?

Tags: python, mathematical-optimization, pyomo

I would like to create a Parameter from another Parameter in an Abstract Pyomo model. Let's assume the following example:

```
from pyomo.environ import AbstractModel, Param, minimize, Var, NonNegativeIntegers, \
    NonNegativeReals, RangeSet, Objective, Constraint, SolverFactory, Set, summation

model = AbstractModel ()

model.S = Set()

model.F = Set()

model.a = Param(model.S)

model.b = Param(model.a * 3)
```

I want every value of the indexed parameter a to be multiplied by 3 so that it becomes parameter b. Another question would be: How can I combine the sets S and F so that they become the set SF?

```
model.SF = Set(within= model.S + model.F)
```

So if the set S would consist of 1,2 and the set F consists of 3,4 then the set SF would consist of 1,2,3,4.

Thanks for Your support!

Comment: This is fairly easy if you use a `ConcreteModel` instead...  Do you have a strong need to do this in an `AbstractModel`?  You can always use regular python to read in data -> python structures -> initialize a `ConcreteModel`...

Comment: I know ```ConcreteModel``` and I could of course just use lists and dictionaries and alter them beforehand. But if there is a solution within the ```AbstractModel``` I would prefer that.

Answer (score 0):

So, it turns out you can.

If you've already tried, you'll note that `pyomo` complains if you try to do any operations on the set before it is constructed.  So, load the data (via whatever means you care to use) and then make a model `instance`.  Note that if you inspect the type for this model `instance` you will see it is a `ConcreteModel`.  So, you can now just add/manipulate parts of that `ConcreteModel` as you like, as long as you refer to it as the "instance" that has been built.  Here is an example... (The data file is not shown, but it is easily inferred from the printout)

```
from pyomo.environ import *

model = AbstractModel()

### SETS
model.I  = Set()
model.J  = Set() 

### PARAMS
model.P = Param(model.I)

data = DataPortal()
data.load(filename='data1.yaml')
instance = model.create_instance(data)

instance.IJ = Set(initialize=instance.I)
instance.IJ.update(instance.J)   # make IJ the union of I, J

instance.P_times_3 = Param(instance.I, initialize={k:3*v for k,v in instance.P.items()})

instance.pprint()
```

#### Yields

```
3 Set Declarations
    I : Size=1, Index=None, Ordered=Insertion
        Key  : Dimen : Domain : Size : Members
        None :     1 :    Any :    4 : {1, 2, 3, 4}
    IJ : Size=1, Index=None, Ordered=Insertion
        Key  : Dimen : Domain : Size : Members
        None :     1 :    Any :    6 : {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}
    J : Size=1, Index=None, Ordered=Insertion
        Key  : Dimen : Domain : Size : Members
        None :     1 :    Any :    2 : {5, 6}

2 Param Declarations
    P : Size=4, Index=I, Domain=Any, Default=None, Mutable=False
        Key : Value
          1 :   100
          2 :   200
          3 :   250
          4 :   300
    P_times_3 : Size=4, Index=I, Domain=Any, Default=None, Mutable=False
        Key : Value
          1 :   300
          2 :   600
          3 :   750
          4 :   900
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I knew that I can manipulate that as soon as the instance is created. However, I hoped there might be the possibility to do that before the instance.